# select id that appears at least (n) times in each group in r

Tags: r

i am working with a huge dataset that have ids and time. Let's say I want to select ids that appear at least two times at month 1 and 2 (in actual data I want to select ids if they appear at least 15 times in specified month). How can I accomplish this in R. Here is the dataset

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 month = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))
```

here is what i want

```
df_1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                   month = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you only want to retrieve the specific months? That is, if month 3 had an entry with id 1 would you retrieve it?

Comment: no, I want to retrieve it if it only appears at least (n) times at specified month.

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  filter(month %in% 1:2, n() >= 2) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#      id month
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     1
# 4     1     2
# 5     1     2
# 6     2     1
# 7     2     1
# 8     2     2
# 9     2     2
```

`data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, .SD[month < 3 & .N >= 2,], by = .(month, id)]
#    month id n
# 1:     1  1 3
# 2:     1  1 3
# 3:     1  1 3
# 4:     2  1 2
# 5:     2  1 2
# 6:     1  2 2
# 7:     1  2 2
# 8:     2  2 2
# 9:     2  2 2
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the intent of OP, but won't this return any `id` that appears >=2 times in any month in the specified range, rather than >=2 times every month?

Comment: Good question ... not sure if "each" or "in all" was intended. The latter is a bit more complicated, of course.

Comment: I think you can first `filter`, then `group_by` and `filter` again : `df %>% filter(month %in% 1:2) %>%  group_by(id, month) %>% filter(n() >= 2) `

Comment: From the question, I read *"at least 15 times in specified month"* as needing to filter by-month, by-id. That doesn't (to me) suggest all months when one month has at least 2. Learner, your thoughts?

Comment: i want to select the id that appears at least two times in specified months. For instance if I want to select ids that appear at least two times in month 1, 2, and 3 and id 1 appears two times in month 3 and 1 but not 2 than I would not select it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty base R solution. Can surely be optimised

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 month = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))

# select months 1 and 2 only 
sel.months <- c(1, 2)
df2 <- df[df$month %in% sel.months,]

# count ids
tb <- as.matrix(table(df2))

# get table rows that are > 2
ids <- as.integer(apply(tb, 2, function(x) {names(which(x >= 2)) })) 
# remove duplicates 
ids <- unique(ids)
# filter data 
df.filtered <- df[df$id %in% ids,]

df.filtered
```

A prettier solution using dplyr

```
library (dplyr) 

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 month = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3))

sel.months <- c(1, 2)

df.filtered <- df %>%
 filter (month %in% sel.months) %>%
 group_by (id, month) %>%
 mutate (count = table(id)) %>%
 filter (count >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select id's that occur atleast two times in the month 1 and 2 :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(sum(month %in% 1:2) >= 2)

#    id month
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     1
#3     1     1
#4     1     2
#5     1     2
#6     2     1
#7     2     1
#8     2     2
#9     2     2
```

The equivalent `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[sum(month %in% 1:2) >= 2], id]
```

and base R solution :

```
subset(df, ave(month %in% 1:2, id, FUN = sum) >= 2)
```